# Differentiate dropdown multi select (without options defined) with regular text columns

Tags: smartsheet-api

Is there any way to differentiate columns that are of type drop down multi select from regular text columns :

This is supposed to be a multi select drop down list without any option :

```
    "id": 5414087443146628,
    "version": 2,
    "index": 2,
    "title": "Column3",
    "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
    "validation": false,
    "width": 150
```

Same question goes for multi contact list without contact options defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of multi-contact or multi-dropdown as new versions of the various GET requests, then its easier to return the correct values. For multi-dropdown, you use a combination of query parameters of "level=3" and "include=objectValue", then you'll see the column type change to MULTI_PICKLIST instead of TEXT. (The TEXT value is to maintain backwards compatibility.)

So, essentially, your request would look something like GET /sheets/{sheetId}?level=3&include=objectValue.

Comment: level=3 doesn't exist, but you were right I had to include level=2 to queries.

Answer (score 0):

To test the scenario you've described, I created the following sheet structure in Smartsheet, where the column names indicate the type of each column:

[image]

Then I used Postman to issue a **Get Sheet** request for that sheet:

`GET https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5831916227192708`

The `columns` portion of the API response looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 5831916227192708,
    ...
    "columns": [
        {
            "id": 1256050323154820,
            "version": 0,
            "index": 0,
            "title": "Description",
            "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
            "primary": true,
            "validation": false,
            "width": 124
        },
        {
            "id": 5759649950525316,
            "version": 0,
            "index": 1,
            "title": "Type=Text/Number",
            "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
            "validation": false,
            "width": 128
        },
        {
            "id": 1323283741206404,
            "version": 0,
            "index": 2,
            "title": "Type=Dropdown (single select)",
            "type": "PICKLIST",
            "validation": false,
            "width": 111
        },
        {
            "id": 7741495861110660,
            "version": 2,
            "index": 3,
            "title": "Type=Dropdown (multiple select)",
            "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
            "validation": false,
            "width": 113
        },
        {
            "id": 3048711514285956,
            "version": 0,
            "index": 4,
            "title": "Type=Contact List (single select)",
            "type": "CONTACT_LIST",
            "validation": false,
            "width": 122
        },
        {
            "id": 3992195570132868,
            "version": 1,
            "index": 5,
            "title": "Type=Contact List (multiple select)",
            "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
            "validation": false,
            "width": 125
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

In this response, we see the following:

- If column type is specified as **Text/Number**, the `type` attribute value is `TEXT_NUMBER`
- If column type is specified as **Dropdown (single select)**, the `type` attribute value is `PICKLIST`
- If column type is specified as **Dropdown (multiple select)**, the `type` attribute value is `TEXT_NUMBER`
- If column type is specified as **Contact List (single select)**, the `type` attribute value is `CONTACT_LIST`
- If column type is specified as **Contact List (multiple select)**, the `type` attribute value is `TEXT_NUMBER`

Therefore, it doesn't seem possible to programmatically differentiate a **Dropdown (multiple select)** column from a **Text/Number** column or a **Contact List (multiple select)** column from a **Text/Number** column, based on column metadata alone. IMO, seems like a bug for the **Dropdown (multiple select)** column type and **Contact List (multiple select)** column type to return `type: TEXT_NUMBER`. Perhaps someone with Smartsheet can comment here to provide more insight into this behavior.

Comment: Check out the contact options available at the top-right of this page: https://developers.smartsheet.com. Seems like you can email them at:  devrel@smartsheet.com.

Answer (score 0):

Did a few tests and level 3 isn't available  : [https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}?level=3](https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/4194320963135364?level=3) :

```
{
  "errorCode": 1018,
  "message": "The value '3' was not valid for the parameter 'level'.",
  "refId": "1godowa5cigf1"
}
```

Although i tried with level 2 and got the info : 
[https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}?level=2&include=objectValue](https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/4194320963135364?level=2&include=objectValue)

Results for a multi drop down list :

```
{
        "id": 5414087443146628,
        "version": 2,
        "index": 2,
        "title": "Column3",
        "type": "MULTI_PICKLIST",
        "options": [
            "a",
            "b"
        ],
        "validation": false,
        "width": 150
    }
```